# adding bootstrap dropdown classes/ navigation classes in wp_nav_menu

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am new in wordpress, how can i add all the classes characteristics of bootstrap navigation menu in wp_nav_menu. I came up with a code to put `$args` in `wp_nav_menu($args)` i also added some classes in bootstrap but not full. How can i add it, everything of the characteristicss of bootstrap navigation menu using `wp_nav_menu`. Thanks.

Here is some of my code:

```
<?php 
        $args = array(
        'container'      => 'div',
        'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
        'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
         );
?>
        <?php wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
```